# c++ use of *& as parameter (Pointer fun, tertiary tree method)

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, methods

I'm trying to write a method which adds a key-value pair to a tertiary tree, but I'm obviously doing something wrong as I get a segfault whenever I reach the marked code

```
void Tree::add(int k, Node *&r)
{
    cout<<"add"<<endl;
    if(r==NULL){
        r = new Node(k);
        //check(heap area);
    }
```

**begin problem code**

```
    else if(r->keyCount == 1){
        cout<<"adding second key";
        if(r->getKey() < k){
            Node * temp = new Node(r->getKey(),k,r->data[0],0);
            delete r;
            r = temp;
            r->keyCount++;
            cout<<"test"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            Node * temp = new Node(k,r->getKey(),0,r->data[0]);
            delete r;
            r = temp;
            r->keyCount++;
            cout<<"test"<<endl;
    }
```

**end code**

```
    }
    else if(k < r->getKey())
    {
        cout<<"left"<<endl;
        add(k,r->child[Node::L]);
    }
    else if(r->keyCount > 1 && k < r->getKey(1))
    {
        cout<<"middle"<<endl;
        add(k,r->child[Node::M]);
    }
    else if(r->keyCount > 1 && k > r->getKey(1))
    {
        cout<<"right"<<endl;
        add(k,r->child[Node::R]);
    }
    else
        r = new Node(k);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, in the case that there is only 1 out of the 2 keys used in this particular node, replace the current node with a new node which has the keys in the appropriate places (lesser val in key[0], greater val in key[1])
How do I do this properly?

My code apparently deletes both the address AND pointer for the old node, but doesn't properly reassign the pointer to the new node.

**EDIT**
updated code. the output is as follows:

```
% p4
Enter pairs consisting of an int and a double. I create a
ternary tree, keeping the data in order, by int. Finish entering
data by pressing ^d
2 2
add
Entering the pair: 2, 2
1 1
add
adding second key to current node
test
Entering the pair: 1, 1
-1 -1
add
left
add
Entering the pair: -1, -1
3 3
add
right
Segmentation Fault
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's a link to a zip containing the entire project if you want to look at all the code: http://sdrv.ms/WSrLfv

**EDIT 3**
More error data - output from gdb on crash

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08051628 in getData (x=@0x8047554) at testTree.cc:26
26            x[k]=d;
Current language:  auto; currently c++
```

**EDIT 4**
stepping through gdb to the segfault:

```
Breakpoint 1, Tree::add (this=0x8047554, k=3, r=@0x8047554) at tree.cc:58
58          cout<<"add"<<endl;
(gdb) n
add
61          if(r==NULL){
(gdb) n
65          else if(r->keyCount == 1){
(gdb) n
87          else if(k < r->getKey())
(gdb) n
92          else if(r->keyCount > 1 && k < r->getKey(1))
(gdb) n
97          else if(r->keyCount > 1 && k > r->getKey(1))
(gdb) n
99              cout<<"right"<<endl;
(gdb) n
right
100             add(k,r->child[Node::R]);
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 1, Tree::add (this=0x8047554, k=3, r=@0x806416c) at tree.cc:58
58          cout<<"add"<<endl;
(gdb) n
add
61          if(r==NULL){
(gdb) n
62              r = new Node(k);
(gdb) n
107     }
(gdb) n
107     }
(gdb) n
Tree::operator[] (this=0x8047554, index=3) at tree.cc:47
47          return *(locate(index,root)->data);
(gdb) n
48      }
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08051628 in getData (x=@0x8047554) at testTree.cc:26
26            x[k]=d;
(gdb)
```

Comment: Wow, you can do *& in C++? Is that a reference of a pointer or a pointer to a reference? I think my brain hurts already...

Comment: @Patashu It's a reference to a pointer

Comment: that's what BEGIN CODE and END CODE are for. I explain what I'm trying to do, and what it's apparently doing instead.  I'm trying to change the value of the pointer in the object calling this method, not the value at the address pointed to by it.

Comment: Exactly what line is segfaulting?

Comment: see comment in tushar's answer

Comment: @didierc I know how to use **, I'm trying to understand why it isn't working with the current implementation, not work around my misunderstanding of it.

Comment: It should work provided the pointer you're passing to `add()` is not indeterminate. I.e., make sure it is NULL before any of this code runs.

Comment: If you use a debugger you'll be able to pinpoint exactly which line is causing the segfault and probably what's causing it as well. Otherwise, help us help you by providing code we can compile.

Comment: in the Node constructor, you do initialize the child array to `{0,0,0}`, right?

Comment: about the `Node::L`, `M`, and `R` constants, what are their definitions?

Comment: Node::L M and R and an enum, representing 0 1 and 2 array indexes.  The node constructor initializes them to NULL (it's an array of Node pointers)  However, the problem happens when I recurse with the right, Null value, child node.  This shouldn't cause a segfault, as passing a Null value as a parameter is totally valid as long as it is handled later, and I do that with my first if statement.

Comment: added a link to the entire project, if you want to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working.

In response to your edit: I noticed something interesting in your ouput:

```
-1 -1
add
left
add
Entering the pair: -1, -1
```

Notice how it says "left" and then it says "add" afterward because of the recursive call. However, in the input that crashes the program you don't see "add" after:

```
3 3
add
right
Segmentation Fault
```

If you look at your `Tree::locate` function:

```
Node * Tree::locate(int k, Node *rt) const
{
if(rt==NULL)
    return rt;
if(k==rt->getKey())
    return rt;
if(rt->keyCount>1 && k==rt->getKey(1))
    return rt;
if(k < rt->getKey())
{
    return locate(k,rt->child[Node::L]);
}
else if(rt->keyCount>1 && k < rt->getKey(1))
{
    return locate(k,rt->child[Node::M]);
}
else if(rt->keyCount>1 && k<rt->getKey(1))
{
    return locate(k,rt->child[Node::R]);
}
else
    return NULL;
}
```

This line:

```
else if(rt->keyCount>1 && k<rt->getKey(1))
```

is the same condition as the previous one, so it is being skipped completely.

Comment: The segfault appears to be happening on the recursive call on the right child node, in the last else if statement.

Comment: well, i checked and the array is declared as Node *child[3];, so it's not an out of bounds error. In addition, Node::R does refer to the number 2, and is declared as enum{L=0,M,R};

Comment: @Dazedy Indeed I just checked your code. Nonetheless the point still stands that it's crashing before `cout << "add"`, I doubt `add()` is even being called, it's crashing before that I think.

Comment: agreed. it's happening after it prints "right", and before it can print "add", so it has to be within add(k,r->child[Node::R]);, most likely in the parameters.

Comment: Could it be that the condition leading to that is incorrect? `else if(r->keyCount > 1 && k > r->getKey(1))`, such that adding `Node::R` would make no sense (and even crash)? Just a thought, I'm still going through your code.

Comment: Wait, I just ran it again, and now it's segfaulting AFTER the add. looks like it's going into the method after all

Comment: honestly I haven't a clue... I was just adding some endl's to make the output easier to read.

Comment: Try running a `backtrace` inside gdb.

Comment: that gives me #0  0x08051628 in getData (x=@0x8047554) at testTree.cc:26
#1  0x08051504 in main () at testTree.cc:10

Comment: see my last edit, i stepped through to the segfault. appears to be right after return *(locate(index,root)->data); on line 47 in Tree::operator[]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26416/discussion-between-dazedy-and-jorge-israel-pena)